# Motion verbs in ている form?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, aspect, verbs-of-motion

I've heard that when a motion verb is seen in ている form, such as 来ている, it is translated as "I came and am now here." If someone were to ask "What are you doing?" and I wanted to respond with "I'm coming to your house," how would that work? If I said あんたの家に来ている, I feel like it would give off the message of "I came to your house and now I'm here." Could I just use simply あんたの家に来る?

Comment: Maybe something like あんたの家に来る途中?

Comment: ^ 「来る」じゃなくて「行く」では・・　英語では聞き手の視点から見るのでcomeだけど日本語では話者の視点から見るので

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard Japanese there are two meanings when a motion verb is put as ている that must be distinguished from context or by addition of other words when you want to be more specific.

Furthermore, in standard Japanese, you do not use 来る about yourself when you are "coming" to someone or somewhere, instead you use 行く.

For example:

> Wienerさんの家に行っている。

can mean both "Now I am at Wiener's house" and "Now, I am going to Wiener's house". Normally the first meaning would be interpreted, that is, the **result** of the action *(the result that you are at the house)* is what is ongoing and not the action itself.

> もうWienerさんの家にいるよ。

= I am already at your house

> 今Wienerの家に行っている最中です。

= I am in the process of going to your house now

But the more natural way of saying it would be to use a different word, e.g. 向｛むか｝う, meaning "to head"

> Wienerさんの家に向かっている。

= I am heading to your house now

This is one reason why I like Kyushu. Here we use 来る about ourselves and we distinguish a finished action where the **result of an action** is active from an **ongoing action**, where the action itself is active:

> 来｛こ｝よる I am coming now
>
> 来｛き｝とる I have come (and I am at your place right now)

This usage is however unfortunately not understood outside of Western Japan.